# Symfony 3.3 frontend stack with encore - globally jquery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, webpack, webpack-encore

I'm trying to make symfony app with materialize css framework. According to official 3.3 docs, I'm using encore to frontend.

I have a problem with jquery plugins globally. I'm tried this:
[Webpack Encore - jQuery plugins out of view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45698467/webpack-encore-jquery-plugins-out-of-view) and this still not working...

So...
My webpack config:

```
var Encore = require("@symfony/webpack-encore");
var webpack = require('webpack');

Encore
    .setOutputPath('web/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .autoProvidejQuery()
    .createSharedEntry('vendor', [
        'materialize-css',
        './assets/js/global.js',
    ])

    .addStyleEntry('global', './assets/scss/global.scss')
    .addEntry("createProfileModule", "./assets/js/modules/createProfile.js")

    .enableSassLoader()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVueLoader()
    .addPlugin(new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
        Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'],
        // In case you imported plugins individually, you must also require them here:
        Util: "exports-loader?Util!bootstrap/js/dist/util",
        Dropdown: "exports-loader?Dropdown!bootstrap/js/dist/dropdown",
    }))
    .enableVersioning()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

in **vendor.js** I'm including global.js with:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('.modal').modal();
    $(".modal .close-btn").on("click", () => {
        $('.modal').modal('close');
    });

    $(".button-collapse").sideNav();

    $("#registerModal form").submit((e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        $(".modal .progress").fadeIn().promise().done(() => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                window.location = "/stworz-profil";
            }, 2500)
        })
    });
});
```

in this file, any jquery plugins works fine.
In **createProfile.js**:

```
$('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
    data: {
        "Gdańsk": null,
        "Gdynia": null,
        "Sopot": null,
        "Warszawa": null,
    },
    limit: 20,
    onAutocomplete: function(val) {

    },
    minLength: 1,
});
```

and when I'm load the page in console I see:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
    at Object../assets/js/modules/createProfile.js (createProfileModule.61543364cceab7b76d2b.js:13)
    at __webpack_require__ (manifest.d41d8cd98f00b204e980.js:55)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (manifest.d41d8cd98f00b204e980.js:26)
    at createProfileModule.61543364cceab7b76d2b.js:1
```

How to provide jquery with plugins globally?

Comment: I assume the magic for jQuery plugins is the exports-loader in the .addPlugin() method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after a few tries I got it.

The solutions is to add $(document).ready before autocomplete